# Solving a system of differential equation for a thermodynamic problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab

I would like to reproduce the results from a publication (https://doi.org/10.1007/s00161-015-0415-8) for verification. For this I want to solve the following system of differential equations:

**$$\dot{x} = \frac{\beta\left(...\right)}{x_0}\left(\mu_{ma} - \left(1-x_0\right)\mu_{ra} - x_0\mu_{c}-\frac{R\Theta}{M}\ln{\frac{x}{x_0-x}}\right),$$
$$\dot{\delta} = -A\left(...\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{x_0}\right)
    \left(d_{ma}\delta - w_{ma}p + e_{ma}\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)\right)$$**
with
$$\beta = \biggl|\frac{x-x_{eq}}{x_{eq}}\biggl|\beta_0\exp{\frac{c_1\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)}{c_2+\Theta-\Theta_0}},$$
$$A = A_0\exp{\frac{c_1\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)}{c_2+\Theta-\Theta_0}}$$
and
$$\mu_{ma}\left(p, \Theta, \delta\right) = \mu_{ma0} + d_{ma}\frac{\delta^2}{2} - \frac{p^2}{2\rho_{ma}\kappa_{ma}} - s_{ma0} \left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right) + e_{ma} \left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)\delta + \frac{\alpha_{ma}}{\rho_{ma}}p\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)
    - w_{ma}p\delta - \frac{\beta_{ma0}}{2}\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)^2 - \left(c_{ma}-\beta_{ma0}\Theta_0\right) \left(\Theta\ln{\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}}-\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)\right),$$

$$\mu_{ra}\left(p, \Theta, \delta\right) = \mu_{ra0} - s_{ra0} \left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right) - \frac{\beta_{ra0}}{2}\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)^2 - \left(c_{ra}-\beta_{ra0}\Theta_0\right) \left(\Theta\ln{\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}}-\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)\right),$$

$$\mu_{c}\left(p, \Theta, \delta\right) = \mu_{c0} - \frac{p^2}{2\rho_{c}\kappa_{c}} - s_{c0} \left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right) + \frac{\alpha_{c}}{\rho_{c}}p\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)
      - \left(c_{c}-\beta_{c}\Theta_0\right) \left(\Theta\ln{\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}}-\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)\right)
      - \frac{\beta_{c}}{2}\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)^2.$$

Values for the parameters can be taken from the following picture:

[Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LStZR.png)

The following equations with the initial values $\Theta=500 K$ and $p=0$ are used as initial values:

$$\delta_{eq} = \frac{1}{d_{ma}}\left(w_{ma}p-e_{ma}\left(\Theta-\Theta_0\right)\right),$$
$$x_{eq} = \frac{x_0}{1+\exp{\left(-\frac{M\left(\mu_{ma}\left(p,\Theta,\delta_{eq}\right)-x_0\mu_c\left(p,\Theta\right)-\left(1-x_0\right)\mu_{ra}\left(\Theta\right)\right)}{R\Theta}\right)}}.$$

As well as the following curves for $\Theta$ as a function of time t:

[Curves for theta as a function of time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr4dM.png)

I use in Matlab the solver ODE15s with the following settings:

```
temp_rate1 = 0.01; 
temp_rate2 = 0.01; 
Tmax = 500; 
Tmin=300 ; 
y0=[x_init delta_init]; 
zyk=2; 
ta=0; 
te=0.5*zyk*(Tmax-Tmin)*(1/abs(temp_rate1)+1/abs(temp_rate2)); 
dt=(te/zyk)/80000; 
tspan = ta:dt:te; 
options=odeset('RelTol',1e-12,'AbsTol',[1e-12 1e-12],'InitialStep',dt/3,'MaxStep',dt); 
[t,y] = ode15s('DGL',tspan,y0, options);
```

Unfortunately, I do not get the results shown in the publication. Below you can see the results from the publication and my generated results. The solver does not converges at a certain point. Furthermore, the typical plateau formation is not reached in the solution I generated. In contrast to the results from the publication, my results show qualitatively the same course for each cooling rate.

[results from the publication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhFqp.png)

[own result of x for Coolingrate 0.01 K/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGixU.png)

[own result of x for Coolingrate 0.1 K/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jPep.png)

[own result of x for Coolingrate 1 K/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C408Z.png)

Can anyone help me further in solving this DGL system? 
Below you will find excerpts from my Matlab code for the DGL.

Thanks a lot! 
Felix

```
t_mid = 200/Cooling_rate

if t < t_mid
    Theta = Tmax - Cooling_rate*t;
else
    Theta = Tmin - Cooling_rate*t_mid + Heating_rate*t;
end

delta_eq = 1/d_ma*(w_ma*p-e_ma*(Theta-Theta_0));

mu_ma = mu_ma0 + d_ma*(y(2)^2)/2 - ...
(p^2)/(2*rho_ma*kappa_ma) - s_ma0*(Theta-Theta_0)+...
e_ma*(Theta-Theta_0)*y(2) + (alpha_ma/rho_ma)*p*...
(Theta-Theta_0)-w_ma*p*y(2) - (beta_ma/2)*...
(Theta-Theta_0)^2-(c_ma-beta_ma*Theta_0)*...
(Theta*log(Theta/Theta_0)-(Theta-Theta_0));


mu_ra = mu_ra0- s_ra0*(Theta-Theta_0)-(beta_ra/2)*...
    (Theta-Theta_0)^2 -(c_ra-beta_ra*Theta_0)*...
    (Theta*log(Theta/Theta_0)-(Theta-Theta_0));


mu_c = mu_c0 - (p^2)/(2*rho_c*kappa_c) - s_c0*(Theta-Theta_0) + ...
       (alpha_c/rho_c)*p*(Theta-Theta_0) - (c_c-beta_c*Theta_0)*...
       (Theta*log(Theta/Theta_0)-(Theta-Theta_0))-beta_c/2*(Theta-Theta_0)^2;
           

mu_ma_delta_eq = mu_ma0 + d_ma*(delta_eq^2)/2 - ...
    (p^2)/(2*rho_ma*kappa_ma) - s_ma0*(Theta-Theta_0)+...
    e_ma*(Theta-Theta_0)*delta_eq + (alpha_ma/rho_ma)*p*...
    (Theta-Theta_0)-w_ma*p*delta_eq - (beta_ma/2)*...
    (Theta-Theta_0)^2-(c_ma-beta_ma*Theta_0)*...
    (Theta*log(Theta/Theta_0)-(Theta-Theta_0));


x_eq = x_0/(1+exp(-(M*(mu_ma_delta_eq-x_0*mu_c-...
    (1-x_0)*mu_ra))/(R*Theta)));


A = A_0*exp((c_1*(Theta-Theta_0))/(c_2+Theta-Theta_0));

beta = abs((Theta-x_eq)/x_eq)^Chi*...
       beta_0*exp((c_1*(Theta-Theta_0))/(c_2+Theta-Theta_0));

% x_dot
x_dot = (beta/x_0)*(mu_ma-(1-x_0)*mu_ra-x_0*mu_c-...
        ((R*Theta)/M)*log(y(1)/(x_0-y(1))));
    

%delta_dot
delta_dot = -A*(1-(y(1)/x_0))*(d_ma*y(2)-w_ma*p+e_ma*(Theta-Theta_0));

%function for ODE-Solver
dydt = zeros(2,1);
dydt(1) = x_dot;
dydt(2) = delta_dot;
```

Comment: You should standardize your form, both in implementation and even more so in talking to people outside your application area. For example in your expression of $\dot{x}$ you have a big complicated constant that can be aggregated into some $c$. You can calculate $c$ using the actual formula for it, but still, it is easier to split it up like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may check your implementation of $\beta$ in the matlab code. Original source states $x-x_\text{eq}$. However you evaluating $\theta - x_\text{eq}$. Maybe you will be able to get the desired solution.
If not, you may contact the authors. As I understand, the corresponding author is professor at an university in Munich. Usually, they will provide you with their source code.